# Show/Hide Logic with BeginCollectionItem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, begincollectionitem

I'm using BeginCollectionItem and I'm trying to figure out how to get each individual collection value to do conditional show/hide logic. For example, if I have the following razor markup:

```
<div class="collection">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem(nameof(Item)))
    {
        <select class="select-class" id="select-id" asp-for="SelectExample">
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
        </select>

        <div class="show-if-b">b is selected</div>
    }
</div>
```

I need to show the "show-if-b" div if the "b" element is selected, else it needs to hide. This logic needs to run onchange of the select **and** when the page loads ("b" could be saved) so I don't always have an event to attach to.

I've tried different approaches with jQuery .closest(), .find(), and .parents() but I can't seem to get the specific select value in each collection.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the client side, `$('select-class').change(function() { $(this).next('.show-if-b').show(); });` and for the server side, you can always check the value of the model property (but your select does not even have a `name` attribute and wont bond to anything so its not really clear what your doing)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry, I'm using ASP.NET Core and I didn't include my `asp-for` tag on my select which generates a `name`. I edited my example to include it. I want to write client side JavaScript logic that checks the value of the select and displays the `show-if-b` div whenever the select is b. I need this logic to run whenever the select is changed and when the page loads. My issue is getting this to work with BeginCollectionItem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think I could use .closest() onchange of the select, but I don't think that will work on page load because I'm not sure how to specify each individual collection to run the logic against.

Comment: Figured out. See answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).next()` in `on("change")` to select your each div element which has `"b is selected"`. I set these elements style display none as a default but you can change this css property according to your model initial value. You can implement like following.

```js
$(".collection .select-class").on("change", function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
     if(val == "a")
     {
         $(this).next().hide();
     }
     else
     {
         $(this).next().show();
     }
     
     
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collection">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <select style="float:left" class="select-class" id="select-id" asp-for="SelectExample">
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
         </select>
         <div class="show-if-b" style="display:none">b is selected</div>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <select style="float:left" class="select-class" id="select-id" asp-for="SelectExample">
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
         </select>
         <div class="show-if-b" style="display:none">b is selected</div>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <select style="float:left" class="select-class" id="select-id" asp-for="SelectExample">
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
         </select>
         <div class="show-if-b" style="display:none">b is selected</div>
       </tr>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "collapsed" class to the div and try using the below css and javascript code(This will hide and unhide the div based on selected value): 
HTML:

```
<div class="show-if-b collapsed">b is selected</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .collapsed{
      display : none;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("change","#select-id",function(){
    if($(this).val() == "b"){
        $(".show-if-b").removeClass("collapsed");
    }
    else{
      $(".show-if-b").addClass("collapsed");
    }
});
```

If you want option "b" to be selected on page load use below code as well

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#select-id").val("b");
           $(".show-if-b").removeClass("collapsed");
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however I don't think your example will work for BeginCollectionItem which creates multiple "repeats" of each id and div. I also don't want to select "b" on page load. I only need to display the `show-if-b` div if "b" is selected in its respective collection.

Answer (score 0):

While @user8175473's answer above will work, I found I can also use jQuery's .each() and .find() functions to loop through each collection:

```
$(".collection").each(function (index)
{
    if ($(this).find("#select-id").val() === "b")
    {
        $(this).find(".show-if-b").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find(".show-if-b").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why didnt you use jquery on change?

Comment: @user8175473 I do use on change. My example above is more of an alternative to using a Model value for showing/hiding on load.

Comment: I see, yes you are right .each is alternative way to make your each div hidden or visible according to condition.